# What is echo.sock in the unix system?

Tags: sockets, unix

I read about echo.sock in the Node.js documentation, that you could attach to echo.sock, but i can not find any information what echo.sock does or what it is?

Echo.sock is not specified to Node.js can i understand as i google, but not what it does.

It says here it is for intercommunication, but not anything about echo.sock.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Socket

The documentation in node.js:
http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener

> To listen on the socket /tmp/echo.sock the third line from the last
>   would just be changed to
>
> `server.listen('/tmp/echo.sock', function() { //'listening' listener`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '/tmp/echo.sock' is just a free name picked by the documentation authors.
The example is to show that you can listen for a socket instead of a port.

The example creates a UNIX socket server with a given path '/tmp/echo.sock'. (See http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_server_listen_path_callback).

Once created, with 'nc' you can then write to the socket to prove that it works.